# PHP 5.4: why can classes override trait methods with a different signature?

Tags: php, inheritance, overriding, traits

I'm wondering if there is any good reason why this behaviour is possible in the current PHP 5.4 implementation:

```php
trait T {
    public function test(PDO $pdo) {}
}

class C {
    use T;
    public function test(DOMDocument $dom) {}
}
```

I thought that the fact that a class uses a trait, guaranteed that this class had a specific interface available. But here, if we inadvertently override the trait method for another purpose, we don't even receive a Strict Standards notice, as with classic inheritance.

Is this specifically allowed on purpose? What for?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This behavior is documented. From php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member
> inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the
> current class override Trait methods, which in return override
> inherited methods.

No reason for notices here.

**Edit:**

I took a look on some more serious literature to shed some light on this topic :) . Looks like that such behavior is a part of traits' definition. They are ment to work this way. This is from research "Traits: Composable Units of Behavior"(Proceedings of the European Conference on Object-Oriented Programming):

> Another property of trait composition is that the composition order is
> irrelevant, and hence conﬂicting trait methods must be explicitly
> disambiguated (cf. section 3.5). Conﬂicts between methods deﬁned in
> classes and methods deﬁned by incorporated traits are resolved using
> the following two precedence rules.
>
> – Class methods take precedence over trait methods.
>
> – Trait methods take precedence over superclass methods. This follows from the ﬂattening property, which states that trait methods behave as if they were deﬁned in the class itself.

You can read more here: http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does indeed say that the class can override the trait's methods, but does not say why it can override it with a different signature!

Comment: As I know, traits in PHP override method the same way as inherited, that means no signature check, only method name.

Comment: @Eugene: I get your point, but that still does not explain why the signature of the method is ignored in case of class method precedence, IMO such a conflict (class method overriding trait method with an incompatible signature) should raise a notice - only, I insist, when the signatures are different; if they are equal, then the precedence rule applies. Is there something I'm still missing, or is there something missing in PHP?

Comment: @Timur: with inheritance, there is a Strict Standards notice, hence my question.

Comment: @Benjamin Heh... Didn't know it. If you are really want to know this, we can look at the sources of PHP to see whats happening there :)